# for looping contents on <div class='col-sm-4'>, but when the content gets too long it for loop skips one place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I for loop my contents that have one image and one title below that image.

```
<div class="row">
<article>
  {% for news in newsInCat %}
  <div class='col-sm-4'>

    <div class="content">
    <figure class="story-image">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}'><img src="{{news.get_image_url}}"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre" width="360" height="267"></a>
    </figure>
      <div id="forever "style="margin-bottom:30px;">
      <a href='{{news.get_absolute_url }}' style="text-decoration:none; color:#282E5C;"><h4 style="font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;">{{news.title}}</h4></a>
  </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</article>
</div>
```

but when {{news.title}} becomes long that it becomes more than one line,the content below that title ruins its form. I'll display the problem with the picture. [image]

the title is long, that it takes two lines. and now the content below that is moved down to lower level
[image]

can someone please help me with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a fixed height to your looped elements

```
article .col-sm-4 {
height:300px;//change this
}
```

Comment: while this works...isn't it a bad idea to set height when using bootstrap?

Comment: note you can add a class to differentiate your style from the other

Comment: maybe it's just a width...I played around with the width when I was using bootstrap and the whole structure bootstrap gave me got ruined.

Comment: with what I have, I tried decreasing the size of my screen and the images overlap which I don't understand because I thought bootstrap covers mobile...I don't think adding height did that...any idea what's going on? I'm using for looping col-sm-4

Comment: i have tried to help you this is the most easy solution, other solution may include experimental css or js libraries

Comment: to make your images responsive add the following class to them `.img-responsive`

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery for every column dynamic same height in row

```
equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }
 });
}

$(window).load(function() {
  equalheight('article .col-sm-4');
});
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work...I'm not very familiar with javascript/jquery so not sure how to fixx them....

Comment: can you please explain some more whit the above awesome looking code? I just copied and pasted but it didn't work...

Comment: Add jQuery library in head

Comment: equalheight function find height of every column in row and set height

Comment: I added jquery library but still no difference...I tried the above css answer, setting height to 400px....compared to css code, what advantage does the above javascript code have?i kinda understand it now but should I use simple css or the above one?

Comment: Above jQuery function find maximum height of column and set to all column height, it is dynamic height as per the inner div height.

Comment: Css height is static and it may be some time hide some text

Comment: what happens if he has 10 divs 9 with 20 lines and one with 500 lines, how will this look like?,lots of space on the 20liners

Comment: Different rows added different heights